# How to enabled/disabled button based on the result from another activity?

Tags: android

i am currently developing an Android game App. But i am having issue regarding passing data in a **Private Void Method** from the Level1.java to the data in LevelPage.java. Here is the code for Level1.java, it is extremely very long coding of nearly to 500 lines of code. So i will only display the if else condition of the score that will allow to unlock the next Level's button.

**Level1.java**

In the AlertDialog, if click on Procceed button which is the positive button, it will directly bring to level 2. But of course, even if pressed Proceed button to proceed to Level 2, it must also ensure Level 2 Button is already enabled. But in the neutral button which is Back button in this case, when go back to LevelPage Activity, it should enabled the Level 2 button.

```
if (score == 30) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Level1.this);
                builder.setTitle("Level 1 Complete!");
                builder.setMessage("You have won! You have unlock level 2! You can proceed to Level 2 or go back.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Proceed", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Level1.this, Level2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                builder.setNeutralButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Level1.this, LevelPage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("30", score);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.show();
                runTimer.cancel();
            }
```

Note that gamePlay() is a private void method which just simply means it will continue the game so simply just ignore that.

**LevelPage.java**

```
btnLevel2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickSound.start();
                Intent i = getIntent();
                i.getSerializableExtra("30");
                if (i.equals("30")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LevelPage.this, Level2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    btnLevel2.setEnabled(false);
                }

            }
        });
```

Now it can actually disabled the button. But i cannot be able to enabled the button even when it score 30 at the level1 activity. I had no idea what went wrong with able to pass the data from level1 activity to levelpage activity of btn2.setonclicklistener()

Comment: you can use startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult()
https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Comment: So if understand your question correctly what you want is when your score hits 30 you are showing an Alertbox and onclicking proceed you are going to lvl2 but if you click back you come back to lvl1 activity but you want the lvl2 button enabled at that time else it should be disabled by default??

Comment: Erm no, for the click back, it means it will go back to the Levels Activity. Not Level 1 activity.  When click Back, it should be able to now enabled lvl2 button. For the proceed button, what i mean is that normally if unlock next level, it can proceed to Level 2 activity. However, my concern for that part is i want to ensure lvl2 button is also enabled already in the levelpage Activity.

Comment: gaurang, i am trying out startActivityForResult() method now. i had been trying that for a while. maybe i got my logic a bit mixed up

Comment: oh in that case it's pretty easy when the user click on back button and you navigate him back to level activity where you have the level2 button send your score with it and put a condition there to check whether score is 30 or not. and if score is 30 set a clicklistner on it.

Comment: Is it ok if you provide the code? It will be easier that way for me to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can do something like this:

builder.setNeutralButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Level1.this, LevelPage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("SCORE", score);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

//In your level activity where you have btnlvl2
// int or String based on what have you decalred your score varaible
Intent i = getIntent();
String score = i.getStringExtra("SCORE");

if (score.equals(30)){
        btnLevel2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickSound.start();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LevelPage.this, Level2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried, but it didnt work. Even when i put in string, "30", in the if (score.equals()) it also wont work

Comment: Is your score variable string or int??
and second print and check what value of score you are getting from the line String score = i.getStringExtra("SCORE");

Comment: Wait nevermind. I had solve it. Now my last issue is regarding the button. I do not know how i can be able to get my lvl2 button to be enabled only once the score reach 30 and it return back to levelpage activity where the lvl2 button is enabled. I can only get it disabled when declared before setting the lvl2.setOnClickListener() method

Comment: how are you disabling it??

Comment: i have to disable it before the setOnClickListener on the lvl 2 button. I am not a really good programmer

Comment: Don't do anything fancy to disable the click just in disabled state give your button a light grey background and when score hits 30 and you go to your level activity use the code I provided and in the if statement change the background and your text color and use the onclicklistner. you'll be fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145886/discussion-between-mobile-developer-and-sumit).